# Minimum and maximum of a serie of points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to write a function which take the coordinates of n points and returns the minimum and the maximum of abscissa and ordinate

For exemple :

```
A = np.array([1,2])
B = np.array([5,-1])
C = np.array([2,4])
t=[A,B,C]
print(limits(t))
```

Return :

```
(1,5,-1,4)
```

I was thinking to create a loop which takes x values and y values and then just with a simple if we can find the max and min, but I dont how to write it..

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far, this is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
A = np.array([1,2])
B = np.array([5,-1])
C = np.array([2,4])
all_coordinates = np.array([A, B, C])
print(all_coordinates)
min_v, max_v = np.array([all_coordinates.min(axis=0), all_coordinates.max(axis=0)])
print(min_v)
print(max_v)
```

The variable `all_coordinates` combines all the coordinates into one array. After that you take the minimums and maximums columns-wise(using `axis=0`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `amin` and `amax` functions of numpy.

```py
A = np.array([1,2])
B = np.array([5,-1])
C = np.array([2,4])

t = np.vstack([A,B,C])

print(np.amin(t, axis=0), np.amax(t, axis=0))
```